# Why is it easy to bring a gun into a school, but not onto an airplane?

Tags: united-states, guns, public-safety

There are occurrences of school shootings in the USA, with people getting very upset about every such incident. But it's very easy to bring a gun into a school: no metal detectors, no guards, no baggage scanning, etc.

Meanwhile you cannot even bring too much water into your carry-on luggage on board of an airplane, not even a baton, not a knife, just no weapons possible. And you may be stripped naked by TSA to ensure that, but also so that they can confiscate any drugs you may have.

Shouldn't compulsory public schools be at least as safe as airplanes are? Sure you cannot bring down a big building with a public school, but you can harm multiple kids and that's a loss. Isn't it neglectful that we're not scanned when we enter public buildings different than airports?

Answer (score 4):

About [3 million people](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/by_the_numbers) fly into and out of US airports per day. I'm not sure if takeoffs and landings are counted twice here. But it gives a ballpark. People have to bring extra time to allow for security when they fly.

About [50 million students](https://nces.ed.gov/fastfacts/display.asp?id=372) are enrolled at school. Add others who are allowed to enter the school, subtract that there are no classes every day of the week. Most of the students would come to school within a brief part of the day. Most people who go through TSA security are adults, most of the rest are accompanied children.

So as a very rough estimate, the effort to secure schools would need several hundred times more staff than TSA, most of them employed on a part-time basis, and it would still force parents with small children to wait quite a long time before they can drop their children and go on to work.

Comment: And that's exactly my point. It sure would require lots of resources. But it would finally make schools safe. Therefore airlines are discriminated against in relation to schools.

Comment: To make things even more complicated, there are about 5200 public airports and 98000 public schools in the US. To make things more complicated yet, TSA checkpoints run 16 hours per day. School arrivals are much more compact in time. @verybigcat, you are missing the main point of this answer, which is that the type of TSA screening used in public airports in the US is not feasible for public schools.

Comment: I'm not satisfied with arguments like "it's not feasible". It often wasn't feasible to have renewable energy, and now some countries have it as a big percentage of their electricity. For year it wasn't feasible to work remotely, and now it is. Once it wasn't feasible to have public hospitals, and now they exist. It wasn't even feasible to have smartphones now, and now we have them.
Government also doesn't seem to worry if it's feasible for taxpayers to pay taxes willingly. Then why do people accept such an excuse for not securing their children, while they also accept existence of TSA?

Comment: @verybigcat, putting the same budget into mental health and realistic anti-bullying programs would save more lives than TSA-style screening. You could also ask why there is no screening in supermarkets, or post offices.

Comment: There's a whole series of articles by Bruce Schneier, an IT and general security expert, on TSA-type activities, tagged [security theater](https://www.schneier.com/tag/security-theater/).  I don't really agree with TSA screening being useless, but they are far from perfect and the notion of generalization to schools seems wishful thinking rather than based on a thorough assessment of their likely cost benefit.

Comment: @o.m. you're not forced to go to supermarkts, or post offices. But you are forced to go to school. And survival isn't guaranteed there. Yes, if kids were promptly punished for bullying, there would be much less chance that somebody commits the actual crime.

Comment: Of course there's a much more feasible and cost-effective way of preventing guns from getting into schools, used by every civilized industrialized country, but we all know that a significant fraction of the US population think children being shot is a price you have to pay for not doing that.

Comment: @verybigcat, prompt punishment for bullying could help introduce a stressful situation which makes somebody snap. They're *children*, they need compassionate education, not being subject to prison-like rules. And children are not forced to go to public school in the same sense that shoppers are not forced to go to supermarkets. There are alternatives, which may be costly or impractical or both.

Comment: @o.m. sure children need compassion from their parents. But if the child bullies somebody, and gets away unpunished, it's only an incentive for more bullying, and calls for a bloody revenge. Compassion is for good people, for violent underage thugs there's violence.The moment your child touches mine, it becomes fair game. Supermarkets have alternatives, you can do gardening or buy vegetables from neighbours. In a free country people were once able to sell potatoes from the streets. And if there were no public schools, you would simply hire a teacher, on your own or together with neighbours.

Comment: One thing to remember is in many schools around the country students are entering and exiting the building throughout the day via many different doors. This includes simple things for changing buildings for different classes, activities for class such as gym, or depending on the grade going to recess. It isn't a simple matter of checking students as they get there for the day (which can have multiple start times depending on the school) but needing to check them multiple times each day.

Comment: @JoeW, such a secured school would need walls, and very few gates. And probably barbed wire on those walls ...

Comment: @o.m. And in the area where I live I have seen very few schools that could meet that criteria.

Comment: @JoeW, re-building the schools on airport (or prison) specifications would be the smallest part of the expenses.

Comment: @o.m. When cities can't even afford to build them now how would they afford that?

Comment: @JoeW, that is just the point of my answer to the OP's suggestion. I explained some of the logistics (timing and staff, in my initial answer) without quite saying out loud that the proposal will *never* fly, because the US can do some amazing things if they *do* set their minds on it.

Answer (score -2):

There were two main impetuses for airline security: the large number of hijackings in the 1970s, and the 9/11 hijacking. The hijackings of the 1970s often involved hijackings for hostages. Hostage-taking at schools is not very common, would be more difficult, and it would be more difficult, both practically and politically, to make entry to schools (especially more middle class schools) subject to airport level security. The 9/11 hijacking added the concern of not only the taking of hostages, but of planes being used as weapons, and of course you can't hijack schools and fly them into skyscrapers. And policies aren't generally completely logical, either. Making going through security a condition of traveling simply feels more reasonable to a lot of people than making going through security a condition of going to school does (at least, again with the caveat of middle class schools). There may also be the issue that hijacking are thought of as being done by foreigners (especially Muslims, and earlier Muslims and communists[1]), while school shootings are done by Americans, and so school shooting are thought of as being done by "bad apples", while hijackings are an attack by "them" in general, rather than just a few individuals.

[1] I'm not saying that hijacking are exclusively Islamic and communist, just that Islamic and communist hijacking are often what people think of when they think of hijackings.